# Is there a way to write a GUI without an event loop?

Tags: c++, user-interface, event-handling, cross-platform

Libraries like Qt provide an event loop that handles UI events, often (or always?) wrapping the OS UI event loop in order to achieve the best results.

Now I can't help wondering if there is a way to write the UI without that master event loop, such that it works on all major OSes.

If this is possible, how would it work, and are there any examples in the wild of an event-loop free UI (preferably in C++)?

Comment: Probably not. Sorry.

Comment: If you don't interact with the OS's event system/queue, how are you (as a userspace program) going to receive events?

Comment: Yes, but you have to write a new operating system from scratch using a technique that hasn't been invented yet to respond to user interactions.

Answer (score 2):

Windows and X11 (Linux) both require that any windows be answerable to Event Callbacks (or be the parent of a window currently answering event callbacks), or else the OS will treat them as though they stopped responding—and on Windows at least, will trigger a "Program X has stopped responding" pop-up.

The semantics of *how* those event callbacks need to be handled is different (namely, Windows requires the "Thread that created the window" to handle them, whereas Linux requires the "Main Thread" to handle them) but the principle is the same.

I'm not familiar with MacOS, but I'd presume it has similar logic.

Comment: Does ***linux*** have notion of _windows_? That's new to me. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Eh, updated. Literally every version of Linux I've used had a GUI in some form or another, so I'm used to lumping them all together as "Linux".

Comment: X11 does have a notion of windows and X has an event loop. I assume that's what's being refered to. But you are absolutely correct that that is not a *Linux* thing - it a *X* thing.

Answer (score 0):

Allnmajor windowing frameworks I am aware of expect to be interacted with with an event loop by gui apps.

Now, you could wrap the ui framework interaction and ferry said events to event broadcasters.

Then the application would just subscribe to being notified.

Now, in some cases, the windowing framework may demand synchonous responses from messages, so in those cases the abstraction will leak a bit.  But otherwise you coukd have an event-loop free GUI app in the client code (the event loop would still exist, but be solely in the cross platform library).

A way to imagine programming in such a framework is that you would set up ui widgets and hook them to code, including hooks like "on app start" which might launch your main window, which in turn hooks more messages.